# Por qué no suma 4

Tags: javascript

***Haciendo un ciclo for en consola no muestra la suma de 4 a cada iteración***

```js
for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
  
  var a = i;
  a += 4;
  console.log(a);  
}
```

Comment: Es curioso porque si imprimes el valor de `i` en tu bucle empieza por 50... Vale, debe de tener algún tipo de límite la consola embebida de Stackoverflow y debe de dejar solamente mostrar 50 registros.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, el código imprime correctamente lon números del 0 al 99 incrementados en 4 es decir del 4 al 103. Si esto no es el resultado esperado entonces por favor explicate mejor.

Comment: En realidad si que suma 4, el fallo esta en que en cada ciclo del for, declaras que a es igual a i, y despues le sumas 4, por lo tanto cuando i = 0, el resultado es 0+4, cuando i es 1 el resultado sera 1+4. El codigo hara una serie de numeros desde el 4 hasta 99+4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al incrementar de esta forma:

```
   for(var i=0;i<100;i++){

      var a = i;
      a += 4;
      console.log(a);  
    }
```

Cada vez que realiza un bucle, la variable se comporta de esta forma:

Analizamos las variables

```
 i     a=i    a=a+4  .... es equivalente a+=4
i=0 -> a=0 -> a=4
i=1 -> a=1 -> a=5
i=2 -> a=2 -> a=6
i=3 -> a=3 -> a=7
```

La forma correcta es incrementar la variable de control (i) directamente en la estructura de definicion del bucle.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i=i+4){

console.log(i); 
}
```

Comment: y porque sobrepasa los 100

Comment: Por que en el for(var i=0;i<100;i++), la variable i si llega a 99, pero le sumamos 4 (a += 4;), que es la variable que representamos en la consola y llega hasta 103 (99+4).

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres incrementar cada 4 solo tienes que hacerlo en el for mismo.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i+=4){
  console.log(i);  
}
```